# Prevent access to mapped network drive

Tags: c++, mfc, network-programming, share

I want to create an MFC application to prevent the access to the mapped network drive. I've tried with API's listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525394(v=vs.85).aspx
but it says about the network drives on the local machine. But I want to prevent a user from accessing the other network drives or folder

Comment: Why don't you just unmap the drive or change permissions on the drive? What have you tried? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I want to create a user application that sets the user rights by the administrator, if the admin wants to block the access to the network resources the application must prevent the access. that's why I'm searching for code

Comment: You should resolve this problem by setting the appropriate permissions. Why do you think you need a program for this. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You are going to jump through hoops doing this in `c++`. There are much easier ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses [Access Control Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872(v=vs.85).aspx) to secure resources. You'll want to create a *discretionary access control list* that *denies* access. [This guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446596(v=vs.85).aspx) shows the steps needed: get existing ACL (if any - else create one), **prefix** the deny entry in the DACL (else it may be pre-empted by an allow entry), and apply the updated ACL.